# Outlook crashing on terminal server for a few users. (Exchange 07)

Tags: exchange-2007

We have about 3 or 4 users (out of 700) whose Outlook clients freeze/crash on our server 2008 terminal servers.

We have deleted their local profile with no luck. We can create a new mailbox, but that leads to problems with other people's autocomplete trying to send to the previous mailbox.

Is there a way to 'repair' a mailbox that is having this kind of problem?

Comment: You need to do a little more troubleshooting on the problem and give us more information. How many items are in the affected mailboxes? How large are the affected mailboxes? Is Outlook configured in cached mode? How do the users connect to Exchange: MAPI, POP, etc.?

Comment: If the users log on to another computer does Outlook still crash?

Comment: Using SMTP.  Not in cached mode.  Mailboxes are not particularly big (less than 2 gig and not the biggest mailboxes we have).   Not sure on exact number of items in mailbox.  Only seems to be crashing on the terminal servers... obviously doesn't matter which computer they connect to the terminal server from.  Doesn't crash on their local desktop.

Comment: When you say the Outlook clients connect via SMTP do you mean POP3/SMTP or do you really mean MAPI? What option do you select when setting up Outlook: Internet E-mail or Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: Do they have roaming or terminal server/remote desktop profiles? You may want to delete them too.

Comment: Oh must be MAPI, When setting up I chose MS Exchange

Comment: Not using roaming profiles.

Comment: Is BCM installed? Also, you might check what plugins are enable e.g. Anti Virus.

Comment: No BCM or plugins.